# Photo Tagging in WPF

Tags: jquery, .net, wpf, image, tagging

I'm looking for something to add tags on images in WPF. Is there some sort of APIs that will do it like the ones in web, for instance jquery  and Facebook APIs. Or we need to tweak it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF does not include a tagging system.

So you will have to add your own.

Overlaying rectangles isn't hard; just put an image control in a grid or canvas and allow the user to draw rectangles on top: [Image crop with custom rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955026/image-crop-with-custom-rectangle/7955339#7955339)

IF you want to include the tags in the image data itself you will need to dive into an image format that allows you to add custom fields to the picture: http://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/deepview/exif.html

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your opinion on Perl, ExifTool is the best: http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/